# mongodb query to find value in json

Tags: java, mongodb

I started working with MongoDB. I prepared some basic training JSON:

```
{
  "header": {
      "Hotel": {
      "data": [
          {
          "name": "Hilton",
          "Id": "1231213421"
          }
      ]
      },
      "standard": "5",
      "priceStage": "4"
  },
  "data": {
      "http": {
      "strean": {}
      }
  }
}
```

and I wrote a query like this:

`db.hotel.find( "data": { Id: "1231213421"})`

Why query does not return anything?

Comment: Because there is no such structure in your json? You have a data inside a header and data is an array `[  ... ]`... You can start from these hints

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to match on an element within an array and you don't need to match on the entire array. So,something like the following will work:

```
db.hotel.find({"header.Hotel.data": {"$elemMatch": {"Id": "1231213421"}}} );
```